# Adding 'Link to Item' in SPView Programmatically

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, development, sharepoint-server

I am trying to add Link to Item to existing SPView in SharePoint 2010.
The same view is further used in ListViewWebpart.

I am using below code to add LinkToItem attribute for field 'SpecificGoal'. Code working fine as I could see that attribute being added to **xmlDoc.OuterXml**. 
However, **ListViewWebpart is not displaying Link to Item.**

Is this a valid way to update the view? Any other way to programmatically adding 'LinkToItem'?

Thank you.

```
string fieldXml = _view.GetViewXml();
fieldXml = CreateLinkToItem(fieldXml);
_view.SetViewXml(fieldXml);
_view.Update();

private string CreateLinkToItem(string fieldXml)
{            
    XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
    xmlDoc.LoadXml(fieldXml);
    const string xpathSourceNodes = @"//FieldRef[contains(@Name,'SpecificGoal')]";
    XmlNode targetNode = xmlDoc.SelectNodes(xpathSourceNodes)[0];
    if (null != targetNode)
    {
        XmlAttribute newAttribute = xmlDoc.CreateAttribute("LinkToItem");
        newAttribute.Value = "TRUE";

        targetNode.Attributes.Append(newAttribute);
        break;
    }     
    return xmlDoc.OuterXml;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfield.linktoitem.aspx),

> Attempts to set this property are ignored if LinkToItemAllowed is not
>   set to Allowed.

So, I would try adding both:

```
LinkToItem="TRUE"
LinkToItemAllowed="Required"
```

Comment: Tried this as well. But no luck.

Comment: @SagarS. try with the lower casing:  linkToItem="true"  (see: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/929deaf8-5372-4907-b965-b2f829da2b5e/linktoitem-not-working-for-any-column)

Comment: Thank you again for replying.
As you suggested, tried lower case but still not showing link to item.

Modified XML is shown properly till method SetViewXML. Once this method is called, again ViewFields are seen without LinkToItem and LinkToItemAllowed attributes. It just removes them.